# Popularity [s4] or consistency [r-s4]: which should prevail when synonymizing tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

The R language has a few frameworks for object oriented programming.  The popular ones are:

- [S3](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/UseMethod.html): [r-s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-s3)
- [S4](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/methods/html/Introduction.html): [r-s4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-s4)[s4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s4)
- [reference classes](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/methods/html/refClass.html): [reference-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reference-class)
- [R6](https://github.com/r-lib/R6/): [r6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r6)

and some people are working on an [S7](https://github.com/rconsortium/OOP-WG/) to [rule them all](https://xkcd.com/927/).

S3 uses [r-s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-s3) exclusively because [s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s3) is a synonym for [amazon-s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-s3).  That's fine, but I wonder if, for that reason, we should be consistent and resolve the S4 duplication by making [s4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s4) a synonym for target [r-s4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-s4), *even though* [s4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s4) is more popular (631 questions, compared to 12).

I'd suggest [s4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s4) → [r-s4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-s4) directly, but I only have score in [s4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s4) owing to its popularity.  I *am* able to suggest [r-s4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-s4) → [s4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s4), but that would entrench the inconsistency with [r-s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-s3).

FWIW, I'm not bothered as much by [r6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r6).  R6 is implemented as an R package, and there is precedent for R packages using tags without the `r-` prefix ([dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dplyr) [rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rcpp) ...).  Conversely, other "conceptual" subsets of [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) often do get the prefix ([r-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-faq) [r-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-package) ...).

Comment: Having gained some score in [tag:r-s4], I've [formally](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r-s4/synonyms) suggested [tag:s4] → [tag:r-s4].  But the number of users able to vote is probably vanishingly small, so I won't hold my breath ...

Comment: I went ahead and approved your suggestion and merged the tags so there is now only the [tag:r-s4] and a synonym [tag:s4] -> [tag:r-s4]. If the s4 tag ever becomes a problem due to the ambiguity/overlap with another topic it can be easily removed by a moderator at any point in the future.